# mongodb / mongoose subdocument aggregation query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

i need to get this output from my schema using mongoose aggregation framework

**my schema**

```
const innerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  responseTime: Number,
  day: String,
  hour: Number
})

let logsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, enum: ['visit', 'new-request', 'new-customer'] },
  series: { type: [innerSchema], default: [] }
})
```

the output that i need is the following

```
        [{
            "name":"visit",
            "series": [
                {
                    "day": "Saturday",
                    "count": 50
                },
                {
                    "day": "Friday",
                    "count": 20
                }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"new-request",
            "series": [
                {
                    "day": "Saturday",
                    "count": 100
                },
                {
                    "day": "Friday",
                    "count": 4
                }
            ]
         }]
```

Currently stuck with this aggregation query

```
  Logs.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        '_id': '$name',
        series: { $first: '$series' }
      }
    },
    { $unwind: '$series' },
    {
      "$group": {
        "_id": '$series.day',
        count: { $sum: 1 }
      }
    },
    { $limit: 7 }

  ])
```

that outputs the following :

```
[
    {
        "_id": "Saterday",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": "Friday",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": "Sunday",
        "count": 5
    }
]
```

it misses the name&series fields

**the series array i need it to be limited to top 7 docs to get a week of data**

**any help is appreciated**

> **NEW ---> UPDATE**

**this is the original data set**

updated it to a simple structure

```
      [
    {
        "_id": "5ea1770c165ece5a40af06ea",
        "name": "new-request",
        "day": "Saturday",
        "hour": 14,
        "createdAt": "2020-04-23T11:07:56.175Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-04-23T11:07:56.175Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ea17770165ece5a40af06eb",
        "name": "new-request",
        "day": "Thursday",
        "hour": 14,
        "createdAt": "2020-04-23T11:09:36.364Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-04-23T11:09:36.364Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ea17770165ece5a40af06ec",
        "name": "new-customer",
        "day": "Thursday",
        "hour": 14,
        "createdAt": "2020-04-23T11:09:36.984Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-04-23T11:09:36.984Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ea17771165ece5a40af06ed",
        "name": "visit",
        "day": "Thursday",
        "hour": 14,
        "createdAt": "2020-04-23T11:09:37.603Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-04-23T11:09:37.603Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ea17772165ece5a40af06ee",
        "name": "visit",
        "day": "Thursday",
        "hour": 14,
        "createdAt": "2020-04-23T11:09:38.207Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-04-23T11:09:38.207Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ea17772165ece5a40af06ef",
        "name": "visit",
        "day": "Saturday",
        "hour": 14,
        "createdAt": "2020-04-23T11:09:38.698Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-04-23T11:09:38.698Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ea17773165ece5a40af06f0",
        "name": "visit",
        "day": "Thursday",
        "hour": 14,
        "createdAt": "2020-04-23T11:09:39.247Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-04-23T11:09:39.247Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ea2dd44030d853950379007",
        "name": "visit",
        "day": "Friday",
        "hour": 15,
        "createdAt": "2020-04-24T12:36:20.867Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-04-24T12:36:20.867Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ea2dd56030d853950379008",
        "name": "visit",
        "day": "Friday",
        "hour": 15,
        "createdAt": "2020-04-24T12:36:38.297Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-04-24T12:36:38.297Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ea2dd58030d853950379009",
        "name": "visit",
        "day": "Friday",
        "hour": 15,
        "createdAt": "2020-04-17T00:36:40.583Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-04-24T12:36:40.583Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ea2dd58030d85395037900a",
        "name": "visit",
        "day": "Friday",
        "hour": 15,
        "createdAt": "2020-04-24T12:36:40.878Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-04-24T12:36:40.878Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

with the help of @AlexZeDim and some adjustments i managed to get it to work but i got one last issue with data sorting 
i need the data to be sorted by the **createdAt**

```
Logs.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$name',
        series: { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$series"
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        createdAt: '$series.createdAt'
      }
    },

    { $match: { createdAt: { $gt: lastWeekDate, $lt: date } } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          name: "$_id",
          day: "$series.day"
        },
        count: {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    },

    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$_id.name",
        series: {
          $addToSet: {
            name: "$_id.day",
            value: {
              $sum: "$count"
            }
          }
        },

      }
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        createdAt: '$createdAt'
      }
    },

    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        name: "$_id",
        series: "$series"
      }
    }
  ])
```

> **Issue solved**

Comment: Please, provide the original exmple/set of data from the collection

Comment: Also, I'm not sure about `.limit` part. If your `series.day` field have value of current DayOfTheWeek the simple group stage will give you exaclty what you need, because there are 7 different days in the week. And when you `limit(7)` you just showing the last 7 values, not 7 unique days of the week.

Comment: You can try using the `$push` operator _instead of_ the `$first` with the _first_ `$group` stage. Check the results after the first group stage.

Comment: by limit i ment that i need the data for last 7 days not all days , aslo i added the original data set , thanks for the reply @AlexZeDim

Comment: changing $first to $push didnt help @prasad_

Comment: @TarikHusin, thank you for updating the original post, I understand that. As I mentioned, `$group` stage guaranteed you unique values from this field. If there are only Mon => Sun value, you'll receive only 7 values.

Comment: i understand do you have an alternative way , what i'm trying to do is getting the number of visits and requests Per day in the structure above  ,so i can preview it in ngx charts @AlexZeDim

Comment: @TarikHusin, check out the answer below please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original dataset: it's not "Saterday", it's «Saturday».
If you really want/need `{ $limit: 7 }` stage, you could always add it by yourself in the end of this query, it gives exactly what you need:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$series"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        name: "$_id",
        day: "$series.day"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.name",
      series: {
        $addToSet: {
          day: "$_id.day",
          count: {
            $sum: "$count"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: "$_id",
      series: "$series"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/swA3o-adXdx)

Comment: cool i appreciate you'r help ,but the limit dosent work i guess i should add a createdAt field to the series records ? , also im using mongoose and in the name field it projects the doc _id , thanks again

Comment: Well, you could remove `$project` stage if you want, and you'll have `_id`: for `visits/new_requests` values instead of `name` As for using `timestamps: true` in your Schema, it a nice idea, but remember how mongo stores date. If so, you could convert `date` field by special `operators` like `$dayOfTheWeek` (or smth like that) each time, to receive current day.

Comment: Also if i can get a week of data where if there is 2 days that has no visit return in the count 0 instead of not showing it at all

Comment: If you want to remove `count: 0` field, then you'll need to use `$cond` operator, for `count: {$eq: 0}`

Comment: thank you for pointing me to the right direction , i've manged to solve the issue :D